# How to delete a file from the server

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript function below where it removes an appended file name from .listImage when the user clicks on the "Delete" button:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="msg">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage">Delete</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="emsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

        $(this).parent().remove();

    });

      return true;   
}
```

But what I want to know is that when the user clicks on the delete button, I also want the file to be deleted from the server. How can this be done?

The folder the files are stored in is known as ImageFiles and the file name code on server side is `$_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]`.

The uploading of files into the server is on a seperate page on a php script which is below:

```
<?php
$result = 0;

if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
    $parts = explode(".",$_FILES['fileImage']['name']);
    $ext = array_pop($parts);
    $base = implode(".",$parts);
    $n = 2;

    while( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$base."_".$n.".".$ext)) $n++;
    $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] = $base."_".$n.".".$ext;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
    "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
    $result = 1;

}
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"],
      "ImageFiles/" . $_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);
      $result = 1;


      }


?>
```

Comment: Your code is prone to attacks. You should never store any server data like paths on the clients! You need to make a handler from where you ajax a unique id assigned only to that file. The handler then verifies the ID and will delete it on the server with out any client knowing any sort of paths or file names. Otherwise I can start deleting your whole system!

Comment: @ppumkin my actual php script where it uploads files is on a seperate age from the javascript, is there a way deleting a file from the server by storing it in that page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this - http://www.php.net/unlink

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<?php
// Delete image from server
unlink($path_to_file);
?>
```

(The unlink ;))

Comment: So just to make sure will the exact code be `unlink($_FILES["fileImage"]["name"]);`

Comment: You must use the path name, in the case of you deleteing an uploaded file use $_FILES["fileImage"]["tmp_name"] instead.
`unlink($_FILES["fileImage"]["temp_name"]);`

Comment: It is giving me a invalid expression flag w error when I have tried this? What does this mean?